# How to hide/show tabs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have four tabs.On loading only the first tab is opened and when we click on the checkboxes corresponding tab is generated and when we unchecked, the tab will be deleted.How can I do this?
My code is

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nithin</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Vipin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Sachin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Ganguly</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Nithin</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Vipin</p>
  </div>
   <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Sachin</p>
  </div>
   <div id="tabs-4">
    <p>Ganguly</p>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-1" value="1">tabs-1 
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-2" value="2">tabs-2 
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-3" value="3">tabs-3 
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-4" value="4">tabs-4 
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

You can check my code from http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/5/

Comment: you have a bad doctype.

Comment: Not relevant but please add labels for the text next to the checkboxes, i hate not being able to toggle checkboxes by clicking the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of deleting the tab, consider hiding it.

You can add the following CSS to make it work.

```
.ui-state-disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/12/

Of course would also need to handle the hiding of corresponding tab content as well.

Comment: Here when I hide the tab its content comes there.Its visible.

Answer (score 0):

Half answer ..for enabling the tab on the cooresponding checkbox click

```
  $(function() {
      $("#tabs").tabs();

    $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

            $('#tabs').tabs({"selected": parseInt($(this).val()-1),"enabled":parseInt($(this).val()-1) });
        }
        });
    });
```